# RSpec TextMate Bundle [spec/autorun (LoadError)]

Tags: ruby, rspec, textmate, textmatebundles

So I updated to the latest [RSpec TextMate Bundle](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle) and I'm no longer able to run spec test with "Command R".

- I have a clean version version of TextMate installed.
- Rspec version 1.3.1 installed and the executable is working
- My project is a gem generated by Mr. Bones.
- No RVM installed

The Project Directory looks like this

```
my_gem_project
  spec
    model_spec.rb
    spec_helper.rb
```

When I run "Command R" from textmate to execute a spec I get this **spec/autorun LoadError**

```
/Users/jspooner/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/rspec/mate.rb:43:in `require': no such file to load -- spec/autorun (LoadError) from /Users/jspooner/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/rspec/mate.rb:43 from /tmp/textmate-command-767.rb:2:in `require' from /tmp/textmate-command-767.rb:2
```

The problem is with RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/spec/mate.rb because it requires spec which raises a `LoadError: no such file to load — spec` error.

I'm not sure why this error is raised.  I can type spec on the command line but I can't require it in a file that is run by textmate.

Here are my current gem versions.

```
gem list --local | grep spec
blue_light_special (0.2.0)
rspec (1.3.1)
rspec-rails (1.3.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem it's because newer versions of the rspec bundle don't require rubygems - this is so it works for people who use other package managing systems (ie Bundler).

The easiest way to sort this is to add a variable in textmate - details are on the rspec-bundle github README - http://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle

- open up TextMate Preferences
- go to the Advanced tab
- add a variable named RUBYOPT with the value rubygems

Comment: Do you know why spec wouldn't be available to textmate?  If I create a new rb doc and require 'spec' I get a load error.  Thanks